# How to test a text clustering application?

Tags: nlp, data-mining, text-mining

I am developing an application to cluster documents according to their topics. I am using the LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) algorithm. Now the prototype is ready and there are some results.

I am looking for a reasonable way to test it. My current approach is to print out the topics and some of their related documents respectively. And manually evaluate them. I can think of the following test points:

- The documents within a topic are on that topic indeed.
- The topics are substantially different from each other.

Is there any best practice to do this? Is there any objective metric for this rather than my subjective evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

1.after training, we get the topic word matrix P(z|w) , every row is the word's prob assign to the topic, so you can print out the top N words of every topic,and eval them , it would be easy comparing to eval topic with document

2.I think the problem you are asking here is whether the training has converged,I simply eval the P(z|w) ,when the P(z|w) is stable , it means model converge at the param (alpha,beta,topic_num)we choose. and when we tune the topic num , we can get the stable P(z|w) respect to all the topic_num, we choose topic_num respect to the max P(z|w) . you can refer to the paper 
http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/papers/sciencetopics.pdf

3.as to how to tune alpha beta, and effcient way to tune topic_num , Hanna M. Wallach do a lot of research about that,I simply do this by intuition,since the dataset is too large http://people.cs.umass.edu/~wallach/